# Change the Cursor explictly without MouseRegion in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-windows

Is it possible to change the appearance of the cursor in a windows and web app without doing so with a MouseRegion? I currently have a custom widget which uses a CustomPainter to paint multiple shapes on the canvas and with a MouseRegion I'm listening to the mouse events (enter/exit) to determine which shapes is the mouse hovering on. My problem is if I use a Mouse Region to wrap the CustomPainter, it will change the cursor even if the user is not on a shape on the canvas but rather is hovering in the space between the shapes.

Is there a way I can explicitly tell flutter to change the cursor to something when I need it, something along the line of, for example `Mouse.of(context) = SystemMouseCursor.text`?

Comment: Would you please have a look if my answer worked for you?

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! I conjunction with an inherited widget/state management solution it seems to be the best solution for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this where you just wrap your entire view in a MouseRegion and then change the cursor with a setState:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; // <----

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  SystemMouseCursor cursor = SystemMouseCursors.zoomIn; // <----

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion( // <----
        cursor: cursor, // <----
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: TextButton(onPressed: () {
              cursor = SystemMouseCursors.grab; // <----
              setState(() {});                  // <----
            }, child: const Text("Change Cursor")),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The `Stack` widget can help you with that. It can be as big as it's unaligned child, so you can use a stack and fill your borders (of a square for example) with a mouse region if you don't want your entire shape inside that for example:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    const SizedBox.square(dimension: 50), //Unpositioned child
    
    //Four sides
    Positioned(
      left: 0,
      top: 3,
      bottom: 3,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (details) => debugPrint(details.toString()),
        child: const MouseRegion(
          cursor: SystemMouseCursors.resizeLeftRight,
          child: SizedBox(width: 3),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      right: 0,
      top: 3,
      bottom: 3,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (details) => debugPrint(details.toString()),
        child: const MouseRegion(
          cursor: SystemMouseCursors.resizeLeftRight,
          child: SizedBox(width: 3),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: 0,
      right: 3,
      left: 3,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (details) => debugPrint(details.toString()),
        child: const MouseRegion(
          cursor: SystemMouseCursors.resizeUpDown,
          child: SizedBox(height: 3),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      right: 3,
      left: 3,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (details) => debugPrint(details.toString()),
        child: const MouseRegion(
          cursor: SystemMouseCursors.resizeUpDown,
          child: SizedBox(height: 3),
        ),
      ),
    ),

    //Four corners
    Positioned(
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (details) => debugPrint(details.toString()),
        child: const MouseRegion(
          cursor: SystemMouseCursors.resizeUpLeft,
          child: SizedBox.square(dimension: 3),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (details) => debugPrint(details.toString()),
        child: const MouseRegion(
          cursor: SystemMouseCursors.resizeUpRight,
          child: SizedBox.square(dimension: 3),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (details) => debugPrint(details.toString()),
        child: const MouseRegion(
          cursor: SystemMouseCursors.resizeDownLeft,
          child: SizedBox.square(dimension: 3),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: (details) => debugPrint(details.toString()),
        child: const MouseRegion(
          cursor: SystemMouseCursors.resizeDownRight,
          child: SizedBox.square(dimension: 3),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```